# Error Detecting Faces with Face-api.js Expected media to be of type HTMLImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement

Tags: javascript, node.js, face-api

I do not understand how I should send an **HTMLImageElement** to the detection routine of face-api.js..
I'm using `node-red` for this implementation..

I have this error :

> `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: toNetInput - expected media to be of type HTMLImageElement | HTMLVideoElement | HTMLCanvasElement | tf.Tensor3D, or to be an element id at /root/.node-red/node_modules/tfjs-image-recognition-base/build/commonjs/dom/toNetInput.js`

And this is the code i'm using :

```js
var fa = global.get('faceapi');
var ca = global.get('canvas');

const {Image, loadImage, ImageData,createCanvas,HTMLCanvasElement,HTMLImageElement } = ca;

fa.env.monkeyPatch({
   Image: HTMLImageElement
})

//Load all the models ... 
Promise.all([
fa.nets.ssdMobilenetv1.loadFromDisk('/home/models'),
fa.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromDisk('/home/models'),
fa.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromDisk('/home/models'),
]).then(Detector).catch((error) =>  node.warn(error));


function Detector(){
   ca.loadImage('URL OF MY PICTURE').then((image) => 
   {
           let detection = fa.detectSingleFace(image).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceDescriptor().then((detect) => {
               if(detect){
                       node.warn('DETECTED..!');
               }
           });
   }).catch((error) =>  node.warn(error) );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and found out that I wasn't sending the right argument to the detectSingleFace() function. I don't know what's inside the *image* value in your code (after loading the image), but be sure that you are sending an HTML element (either Video, Canvas or Image).

For example:

```
<img id="image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVB...." alt="image">
```

Beware that the image should be in base64.

If the problem persist, you could try running the repo project and see how the data is being handle, at least this worked for me with the **examples-browser** folder.

Hope this helps you,

Comment: I was sending a blank image (new Image(w,h)) for initialization of face_mesh wasm and I was getting exception. 
Your comment "Beware that the image should be in base64." saved me